# Is there way to get the fields as a JSON object instead of string from Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: javascript, json, url, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

By using url like `https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/mysheetid/od6/public/basic?alt=json`

I got field data are under `entry` as array, and within each, the content are get as plain string that can be problematic to parse. For example when content of a field becomes like `content: abc is here` and the colon is separator. It is ok for many cases. But I tried when I change the field value that includes values that is not just `abc` but `ab content: c` then it can be easily confused, well, **without** writing much parsing code.

I want to know if writing this sort of parser is necessary to get all the values in fields as actual objects, or I just have to write that myself? (I know how, but I do not want to reinvent the wheel if Google Spreadsheet already provides such a feature that I just don't know about).

Example:

```html
{
  "encoding": "UTF-8",
  "feed": {
    "author": [
      {
        "email": {
          "$t": "adamchenwei@gmail.com"
        },
        "name": {
          "$t": "adamchenwei"
        }
      }
    ],
    "category": [
      {
        "scheme": "http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006",
        "term": "http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006#list"
      }
    ],
    "entry": [
      {
        "category": [
          {
            "scheme": "http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006",
            "term": "http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006#list"
          }
        ],
        "content": {
          "$t": "_cokwr: some value: afield:",
          "type": "text"
        },
        "id": {
          "$t": "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1DvBoPjfiGNft4IcDwTKYNHYq_FLDlU5_4oI7AOhPzaM/od6/public/basic/cokwr"
        },
        "link": [
          {
            "href": "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1DvBoPjfiGNft4IcDwTKYNHYq_FLDlU5_4oI7AOhPzaM/od6/public/basic/cokwr",
            "rel": "self",
            "type": "application/atom+xml"
          }
        ],
        "title": {
          "$t": "afield",
          "type": "text"
        },
        "updated": {
          "$t": "2017-01-15T15:05:08.549Z"
        }
      },
      {
        "category": [
          {
            "scheme": "http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006",
            "term": "http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006#list"
          }
        ],
        "content": {
          "$t": "_cokwr: antoerh value",
          "type": "text"
        },
        "id": {
          "$t": "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1DvBoPjfiGNft4IcDwTKYNHYq_FLDlU5_4oI7AOhPzaM/od6/public/basic/cpzh4"
        },
        "link": [
          {
            "href": "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1DvBoPjfiGNft4IcDwTKYNHYq_FLDlU5_4oI7AOhPzaM/od6/public/basic/cpzh4",
            "rel": "self",
            "type": "application/atom+xml"
          }
        ],
        "title": {
          "$t": "antoerh",
          "type": "text"
        },
        "updated": {
          "$t": "2017-01-15T15:05:08.549Z"
        }
      },
      {
        "category": [
          {
            "scheme": "http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006",
            "term": "http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006#list"
          }
        ],
        "content": {
          "$t": "_cokwr: 3rd something",
          "type": "text"
        },
        "id": {
          "$t": "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1DvBoPjfiGNft4IcDwTKYNHYq_FLDlU5_4oI7AOhPzaM/od6/public/basic/cre1l"
        },
        "link": [
          {
            "href": "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1DvBoPjfiGNft4IcDwTKYNHYq_FLDlU5_4oI7AOhPzaM/od6/public/basic/cre1l",
            "rel": "self",
            "type": "application/atom+xml"
          }
        ],
        "title": {
          "$t": " 3rd",
          "type": "text"
        },
        "updated": {
          "$t": "2017-01-15T15:05:08.549Z"
        }
      },
      {
        "category": [
          {
            "scheme": "http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006",
            "term": "http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006#list"
          }
        ],
        "content": {
          "$t": "_cokwr: ,heyNewField:",
          "type": "text"
        },
        "id": {
          "$t": "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1DvBoPjfiGNft4IcDwTKYNHYq_FLDlU5_4oI7AOhPzaM/od6/public/basic/chk2m"
        },
        "link": [
          {
            "href": "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1DvBoPjfiGNft4IcDwTKYNHYq_FLDlU5_4oI7AOhPzaM/od6/public/basic/chk2m",
            "rel": "self",
            "type": "application/atom+xml"
          }
        ],
        "title": {
          "$t": "heyNewField",
          "type": "text"
        },
        "updated": {
          "$t": "2017-01-15T15:05:08.549Z"
        }
      }
    ],
    "id": {
      "$t": "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1DvBoPjfiGNft4IcDwTKYNHYq_FLDlU5_4oI7AOhPzaM/od6/public/basic"
    },
    "link": [
      {
        "href": "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DvBoPjfiGNft4IcDwTKYNHYq_FLDlU5_4oI7AOhPzaM/pubhtml",
        "rel": "alternate",
        "type": "application/atom+xml"
      },
      {
        "href": "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1DvBoPjfiGNft4IcDwTKYNHYq_FLDlU5_4oI7AOhPzaM/od6/public/basic",
        "rel": "http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#feed",
        "type": "application/atom+xml"
      },
      {
        "href": "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1DvBoPjfiGNft4IcDwTKYNHYq_FLDlU5_4oI7AOhPzaM/od6/public/basic",
        "rel": "http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#post",
        "type": "application/atom+xml"
      },
      {
        "href": "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1DvBoPjfiGNft4IcDwTKYNHYq_FLDlU5_4oI7AOhPzaM/od6/public/basic?alt=json",
        "rel": "self",
        "type": "application/atom+xml"
      }
    ],
    "openSearch$startIndex": {
      "$t": "1"
    },
    "openSearch$totalResults": {
      "$t": "4"
    },
    "title": {
      "$t": "Sheet1",
      "type": "text"
    },
    "updated": {
      "$t": "2017-01-15T15:05:08.549Z"
    },
    "xmlns": "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom",
    "xmlns$gsx": "http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006/extended",
    "xmlns$openSearch": "http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearchrss/1.0/"
  },
  "version": "1.0"
}
```

Comment: What is an "actual json object"? There are objects. And there are string representations of objects using notation called JSON.  The latter is transformed to former using `JSON.parse`.

Comment: @zaq I attached an example of the data

Comment: @zaq as you can see it's strings with `:`. Is there ways I can query them, like if its sql so only get those needed as json objects? instead of strings then have to parse again?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as "JSON object". There are objects, and there are strings representing those objects in JSON. You get a string, and use `obj = JSON.parse(str)` to parse it into an object. The content of the cells is buried a few layers deep in that object, it's accessed with

```
var content = obj.feed.entry[0].content.$t
```

(or another index in place of 0). Don't worry about the contents  containing colons and whatnot, they are correctly delimited by quote marks, and will be parsed out correctly. Of course you should not be writing your own JSON parser; there is one [built in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) in JavaScript.

---

Additionally, you may be able to use json-in-script with callback: replace `basic?alt=json` with

```
basic?alt=json-in-script&amp;callback=yourFunction
```

at the end of the request URL. Here yourFunction is the name of a function in the JS file executing the request. This function will be called with an argument being the object that's already parsed from that JSON string. This approach avoids CORS issues, in addition to saving one parsing step.

Both ?alt=json and ?alt=json-in-script are legacy API, but apparently they still work.

Answer (score 1):

Try "values?alt=json" instead of  "basic?alt=json"
By using using 'basic' you will get your spreadsheet data in string format and via 'values' you will get your spreadsheet data in a object format